# How to make :render => nothing work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an jquery AJAX call that loads a window. In the window, there is a form with a submit to allow the users to download an item. **I have to make this second form use a regular submit so that I can prompt a download.**
My problem is when there is no file to download, it redirects to the page in which this file is located.
I am trying many different styles of getting it to render nothing, but none of them seem to work.

```
unless params[:controller] == "reports"
  unless @jobs.present?
   flash.now[:error] = "No work orders for this selection."
   render :nothing => true
 end
end
```

Also

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html { render :nothing => true }
end
```

Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: `respond_to do |format|
   format.html { render :nothing => true }
end` works for me.

Comment: does `return render :nothing => true` make any difference?

Comment: are you sure `@jobs` is blank? the render should work, so it might be the condition that skips the `render :nothing => true`

Comment: It definately falls down the pipeline correctly. No worries about the params not matching up to reach the `:render => nothing` param. The problem lies in the fact that this AJAX popup is coming from another controller, so when I try `return false` or `render :nothing` , it's still going to try and reload the page to something ( I guess it defaults to whatever controller action that it's on ), despite the fact that I'm very explicitly telling it not to.) Ah because! most importantly, this is a `submit` not an AJAX request. I can't do an AJAX request because you can't force a download with those

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't use `render: nothing.` This will "fail" ajax request.
Instead, use:

```
render json: nil, status: :ok
```